# Q: Delete WIoTP Resource Group

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot

I've created some resource groups as pointed out in:
    https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/rlac.html#configure_RLAC

I assigned defined users to have access to these groups, then
removed that access and decided to have different groups. After
a while of struggle, I decided that groups cannot be deleted.
I've detached them from users, which makes `"resourceCount" : 0`,
but they have `"subjectRefCount"` as well.

So DELETE gives: `{"message":"CUDRS0067E: The group must not be deleted since it is a resource group of a subject.","exception":{"id":"CUDRS0067E","properties":[]}}`

What can I check/do to delete such resource group ?

Comment: Here is the IotT documentation on how to delete a resource group: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/gateways/gateway-access-control.html#crt_del_groups

Comment: Isn't that device authorization? My case is user authorization. I use <id>.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/groups/<g-uid> to see the group. Same url with method DELETE gives the error.

Comment: please can you provide your org ID so I can check the logs @jarkko ?

Comment: Used other channels to provide Paul the ID.

Comment: It looks like it will be worked upon in coming releases. Luckily I was using searchTags, so as a workaround I removed searchTags and changed name to "deprecated_*" for those that needed delete.